# .htaccess.cpmh3129 - What Is This File?

Tags: joomla, permissions

Running a full Akeeba backup of my site produced this error:
**WARNING |20230728 11:28:40|Unreadable file administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/IDS/.htaccess.cpmh3129. Check permissions.**

The file is inaccessable through CPanel file manager and permissions cannot be changed.
**What does this file do?  Is it necessary or can I delete it?**
I found almost nothing abotu this file from an internet search.

Comment: If there is an original .htaccess file in the "/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/IDS" directory, deleting it should not cause any issues. The contents of the original .htaccess file are as follows:

```# in case PHPIDS is placed in the web-root
deny from all

# silence is golden
php_flag display_errors off```